# Unable to get Video + VideoJS to play MP4s on ANY Android device

Tags: files, .htaccess

This is a multi-part question - I'm running Drupal 7.14, w/ [Video Module 7.x-2.9](http://drupal.org/project/video) and VideoJS Module 7.x-2.2, configured a Content Type to upload only MP4s, and Manage Display to use Video settings, where the Players for all Formats are set to [VideoJs](http://videojs.com/) - and I get videos to playback on all modern browsers - chrome, firefox, safari, ie, iphone/ipad, windows 8 smart phone, just NOT any of the android devices.

I actually tested a Samsung Galaxy S1 Tablet w/ Adobe Flash 6.3 installed, and I still couldn't get the VideoJS 3.0 Flash Fallback [that I normally get on Firefox].

Anyways, the other part of the question is where to actually put my .htaccess file in a multi-site installation that I have my mime type set to video/mp4 .mp4? I'm guessing this may have something to do with it on Android?

I've scoured videojs forums, video/videojs module bug tracking, and couldn't really answer this question. Any advice would help. ALso, I don't have autoplay enabled as a setting on Video Module.

Thanks,

Comment: hrm, quick update - I had a friend update their Android Ice Cream 4.0 phone they bought June 2012 - and the video now shows. It appears Adobe has cut support for Flash on Android after Ice Cream, but the tablet is on JellyBean, so still not clear.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/video is helpful to see where the video tag works. http://caniuse.com/mpeg4 is helpful to see where current browser support is for MPEG-4. There is also another link on that page (bottom) talking about android video. I'm scouring around on a similar topic myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many issues with playback are usually due to improperly formatted/encoded files. Different browsers/devices do not support the same media formats in their implementations of HTML 5 video. This due to mainly patent issues, open-source vs. proprietary and disagreement over which is the "best" format.

To make your video work in the latest versions of all major browsers, you will need to serve your video in both WebM format and MP4 format. To guarantee the broadest range of browser/device compatibility you may also need to include the Ogg format.

WebM: Firefox 4+, Chrome and Opera 10.6+
MP4: Internet Explorer and Safari
Ogg: Firefox 3.5+, Opera 10.5+

Go to http://html5test.com/ using your test devices to see what formats are supported.

Helpful info:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/#media_formats

http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/formats/

Comment: That html5test is a lifesaver. I'm noticing your points, I re-encoded some of the videos manually using latest version of handbrake, and they seem to play over some of the other ones. Thanks alot for the insight!

Comment: When doing mp4 encoding, make sure to place the MOOV atom at the front of the file. Iirc in handbrake enable fast web start or something like that. Sorry I am on my phone and don't have handbrake in front of me to double check